# Python PIL Image.tostring('raw') and IplImage->imageData of OpenCV

Tags: c++, python, c, opencv, python-imaging-library

As stated in documentation:

**IplImage.imageData (from OpenCV library):**

> A pointer to the aligned image data

**Image.tostring() (from Python PIL):**

> Returns a string containing pixel data, using the standard "raw"
>   encoder.

What is the difference between the results of `Image.tostring()` and `IplImage.imageData` ? What should I do if I want to get exactly the same data as returned by `IplImage.imageData` in Python ?

**EDIT:**
Just to clarify, I need to use PIL to load images as I have a python service to receive data from internet and there's no straightforward way in OpenCV to load an image from memory instead of disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Opencv image, pixel data is ordered as BGR, in PIL it is RGB.
You can convert a PIL image data to opencv as below.

```
import Image, cv
pi = Image.open('building.jpg')       # PIL image
cv_im = cv.CreateImageHeader(pi.size, cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3)
cv.SetData(cv_im, pi.tostring())
```

For more information here.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/cookbook.html

Comment: Then how can I get the image data ? `cv_im.tostring()` doesn't seem to return what I need.

Comment: Figured it out:

`cv_im_new = cv.CloneImage(cv_im);
cv.CvtColor(cv_im, cv_im_new, cv.CV_RGB2BGR);`
then `cv_im_new.tostring()` is what I need. I hope there's a better way, IMO cv.CloneImage() would be slow.

Answer (score 3):

There is a straightforward way of reading images from memory in opencv.

## Using cv (version 1)

```
import cv

# First get the compressed image data. This can be retrieved from
# a socket, a file, or whatever you want.
jpegdata = open('myimage.jpg','r').read()

# Create an opencv matrix to hold the compressed data
cvmat = cv.CreateMatHeader(1, len(jpegdata), cv.CV_8U)
cv.SetData(cvmat, jpegdata, len(jpegdata))

# Now let opencv decompress your image
cvimage = cv.DecodeImage(cvmat, cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
```

## Using cv2 (and numpy)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# First get the compressed image data. This can be retrieved from
# a socket, a file, or whatever you want.    
jpegdata = open('myimage.jpg','r').read()

# Convert your compressed data to a numpy array
nparr = np.fromstring(jpegdata, np.uint8)

# Now use imdecode to decompress it
cvimage = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
```